# How To Clear Rich Text box Using A Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, richtextbox

How do you clear a rich text box using a button?

```
    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        presentedCSRRichText.Text.Clear();
    }
```

it's probably really simple to do and i can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    presentedCSRRichText.Clear();
}
```